# Foreach R concatenate Results

Tags: r

I am trying to run a function that returns a xts series in parallel. I need to have the results `cbind` to a matrix but am stuck on how to get it working.

```
fun = function(name,x){
  mat = matrix(1:100)
  mat = mat + x
  colnames(mat) = name
  return(mat)
}

y = 1:26
name = LETTERS
mat = c()
foreach(j=1:length(y) ) %dopar% mat = cbind(mat,fun(name[j],y[j]))
```

The above is a really simplistic example. I would like to end up with `mat` to have 26 columns named A:Z and then have each row be 1:100 plus the current iteration index.

A litter about what I am actually doing. I am running 1 million bactests that taken 1 million different inputs. Each input is stored in a similar `y`. The output of the backtests are signals `1 or 0` and they are xts objects. I hope this provides a similar background.

Thanks

Comment: Can you output it as a `list` and then later make it into a matrix?

Comment: sound be fine, but then how long does it take to convert a list length 1 million to a matrix? `do.call(cbind,aList)` is the way I would go about it, but now sure the speed...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you question, I think you can just set `.combine=cbind` in your `foreach` call and drop the `mat = cbind(mat,...)` from the body of your expression:

```
library(foreach)
library(doSNOW)
##
cl <- makeCluster(3,"SOCK")
registerDoSNOW(cl)
newMat <- foreach(j=1:length(y),
                  .combine=cbind) %dopar% {
                    fun(name[j],y[j])
                  }
##
stopCluster(cl)
```

For the sake of saving space, I'll just post the first 10 and last 10 rows:

```
R> newMat[1:10,1:26]
       A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M  N  O  P  Q  R  S  T  U  V  W  X  Y  Z
 [1,]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27
 [2,]  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28
 [3,]  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
 [4,]  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
 [5,]  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
 [6,]  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32
 [7,]  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33
 [8,]  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34
 [9,] 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35
[10,] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36
R> newMat[90:100,1:26]
        A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   N   O   P   Q   R   S   T   U   V   W
 [1,]  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113
 [2,]  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114
 [3,]  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115
 [4,]  94  95  96  97  98  99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116
 [5,]  95  96  97  98  99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117
 [6,]  96  97  98  99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118
 [7,]  97  98  99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119
 [8,]  98  99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120
 [9,]  99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121
[10,] 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122
[11,] 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123
        X   Y   Z
 [1,] 114 115 116
 [2,] 115 116 117
 [3,] 116 117 118
 [4,] 117 118 119
 [5,] 118 119 120
 [6,] 119 120 121
 [7,] 120 121 122
 [8,] 121 122 123
 [9,] 122 123 124
[10,] 123 124 125
[11,] 124 125 126
```

---

**Data:**

```
fun <- function(name,x){
  mat <- matrix(1:100)
  mat <- mat + x
  colnames(mat) = name
  return(mat)
}
##
y <- 1:26
name <- LETTERS
```